# Expected value of applying the product of the sigmoid-like function to a normal distribution

Tags: expected-value, kernel-trick

Let $\sigma : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a sigmoid-like function, $b \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, $x_1 \in \mathbb{R} $, and $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can we obtain a closed-form solution of $\mathbb{E}[\sigma(x_1 + b)*\sigma(x_2 + b)]$ ?

As written in [this page](http://eelxpeng.github.io/blog/2017/03/10/Tricks-of-Sigmoid-Function), probit is sometimes used for an approximation of the sigmoid function. It is acceptable for our case.
The difference is that the target is the expected value of the **product** of the sigmoid-like function outputs, and the arguments of the sigmoid-like functions have the biases $x_1$ and $x_2$ on them.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: An exact solution is found with numerical methods only. Jensen's inequality *might* apply to calculating some bounds in finite samples. For asymptotic result, reference $\delta$-method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. @AdamO. Could it be shown that there is no closed solution?